# Extjs 4 data store and php

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

I wanna know if it's possible to call php api like in extjs 3.x.x.
Let me explain, I have a store and I want to get data from php :

```
Ext.define('KY.store.watcherStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'KY.model.WatcherModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/admin/rest/ksThresholdWatcher/loadAllRef',
        //reader: {
        //    type: 'json'
        //},
    }
});
```

The url param calls ksThresholdWatcher.php method `loadAllRef` (I have a php rest api);
but it never calls my php script. I'm stuck, I don't now how to do, all examples I see set url param like this url:'myPHP.php'.

How can I make it work my way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the your proxy is `type: 'rest'` in the config. Here is an [example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/restful/restful.html) the restful way. [This](http://edspencer.net/2011/02/proxies-extjs-4.html) also has some good pointers on proxy usage.

You can use the `api` proxy config item in 4.x.x to specify different sources for the different request operations (CREATE, UPDATE, DESTROY, READ).